# open_basedir vs sessions

Tags: linux, php5

On a virtual hosting server I have the open_basedir set to .:/path/to/vhost/web:/tmp:/usr/share/pear for each virtual host. I have a client who's running WordPress and he's complaining about open_basedir errors thus:

> PHP WARNING: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/lib/php/session/sess_42k7jn3vjenj43g3njorrnrmf2) is not
>   within the allowed path(s):
>   (.:/path/to/vhost/web:/tmp:/usr/share/pear)

So the PHP session save_path isn't included in open_basedir but sessions across all sites on the server seems to be working fine apart from in this intermittent instance. I thought that perhaps the default session handler ignored open_basedir and this warning was caused by WP accessing the session file directly.

However from what I can see PHP 5.2.4 introduced open_basedir checking to the session.save_path config: http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.4 (I am on PHP 5.2.13).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create directories (like "phptmp") for the sessions in each of virtual hosts path (preserve permissions and owner), then add session.save_path, upload_tmp_dir for each virtualhost. This is the secure way.
If you'll clarify how virtualhosts are defined (control panel, manually) - we can give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question here was asked a long time ago, Google still seems to be directing a lot of traffic here, and the previous answer is not secure.

I have tested this with PHP 7.2 and 7.4 on Ubuntu. PHP will happily write session data outside of the open_basedir directory using the default handler. It should not work with a custom handler or with older versions of PHP - it might not work in future. So it is therefore good practice to ensure that the session.save_path is within the open_basedir constraint.

If this needs to be inside the document root, then you need to tell the webserver not to allow PHP to execute the PHP in the session.save_path tree. Even if you've told it to only execute PHP in files with a .php extension (there are other pontetial vulnerabilities which allow and attacker to force the name of the session file).